# a static AWGN channel

Tags: homework

Consider  a static AWGN channel 
$$
Y = hX+N
$$
where $h$ is a constant channel gain and the noise $N(0,N_1)$ is independent of the input $X$.  The input is from a 2-PAM constellation, i.e., $X \in \ \left\{+√p,-√p \right\}$ with equal probability where $X= +√p$ is used to send a bit at 1 and $X=-√p$ is used to send a bit at 0.  The decision rule is follows: decide that 1 was sent if $Y>0$ and 0 otherwise.

1. Find the probability of error as a function of $SNR:=\left|h\right|^2 P/N_1$ (express it through the $Q$ function).
2. what is approximately the behavior of the average probability of error when $SNR>>1$?

Comment: This is very much a homework problem in a digital communications course offered in an electrical engineering department, and is probably better asked on dsp.SE or electronics.SE. I have flagged it for migration to dsp.SE.

Comment: Hint: _Conditioned_ on $X = \sqrt{p}$, $Y$ is a Gaussian random variable. Can you figure out its mean and variance? If so, can you figure out the (conditional) probability that $Y < 0$?